# satellizer then not called after authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, satellizer

I'm very new to angular, so my knowledge is based on tutorials and even then I don't succeed. 
I need to authenticate using a google account. That works, I get a token where my api calls could be authorized with. But after login the pop up window should dismiss and I should be redirected to the homepage. This doesn't work.

this is my controller

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$auth', '$location','loginService', loginController]);

function loginController($scope, $auth, $location, loginService) {
    $scope.authenticate = function(provider) {
        $auth.authenticate(provider).then(function(data) {
            loginService.saveToken(data.data.token);
            console.log('You have successfully signed in with ' + provider + '!');
            $location.path('http://localhost/#/home');
        });
    };
};
```

in app.js I have my configuration. this is not my work but a friend who is an intern as wel as me, he is responsible for a mobile application, where he uses the same function to get his token, and it works.

```
authProvider.google({
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/users/signIn'
        });
        $authProvider.storage = 'localStorage'; // or 'sessionStorage'
        $authProvider.loginRedirect = 'http://localhost/#/home';
```

This is the controller in node where the url is redirected to (google developer console)

```
router.get('/signIn', function(req, res) {
    //console.log(req);
    var code = req.query.code;
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
        if (!err) {
            https.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=" + tokens.access_token, function(response) {
                // Continuously update stream with data
                var body = '';
                response.setEncoding('utf8');
                response.on('data', function(d) {
                    body += d;
                });

                // Data fetched
                response.on('end', function() {
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
                    // Check if client_id is from the right app
                    if (parsed.issued_to == '343234242055-vd082vo0o8r8lmfvp1a973736fd98dht.apps.googleusercontent.com') {
                        User.getGoogleId(parsed.user_id, function(err, user) {
                            if (err) {
                                res.status(500).send({
                                    message: 'not authorized app'
                                });
                            }

                            // No user returned, create one
                            if (!user) {

                                // Request user info
                                oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
                                plus.people.get({
                                    userId: 'me',
                                    auth: oauth2Client
                                }, function(err, plusUser) {
                                    if (err) res.status(500).send({
                                        message: 'not authorized app'
                                    });
                                    else {

                                        // Create new user
                                        User.create(plusUser.name.givenName, plusUser.name.familyName, (plusUser.name.givenName + "." + plusUser.name.familyName + "@cozmos.be").toLowerCase(), parsed.user_id, function(err, newUser) {
                                            if (err) res.status(500).send({
                                                message: 'not authorized app'
                                            });
                                            else {
                                                res.statusCode = 200;
                                                return res.send({
                                                    response: 'Success',
                                                    id: user._id,
                                                    firstName: user.firstName,
                                                    lastName: user.lastName,
                                                    email: user.email,
                                                    token: tokens.access_token
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                // Return user
                                res.statusCode = 200;
                                return res.send({
                                    response: 'Success',
                                    id: user._id,
                                    firstName: user.firstName,
                                    lastName: user.lastName,
                                    email: user.email,
                                    token: tokens.access_token
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    // if not right app, return unauthorized response
                    else {
                        res.status(500).send({
                            message: 'not authorized app'
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });

});
```

So I login, I get asked to give permission to the application to use my account info, I get a json response where I can see my name, email and token, and that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even within the company where I work, no one could find an answer. So I came with a solution myself. I don't use satellizer anymore.

```
 .when('/access_token=:access_token', {
            template: '',
            controller: function($window, $http, $location, $rootScope) {
                var hash = $location.path().substr(1);

                var splitted = hash.split('&');
                var params = {};

                for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
                    var param = splitted[i].split('=');
                    var key = param[0];
                    var value = param[1];
                    params[key] = value;
                    $rootScope.accesstoken = params;
                }
                console.log(params.access_token);
                var json = {
                    Token: params.access_token
                };
                $window.localStorage['token'] = params.access_token;
                $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users/signIn', json).success(function(data, status) {
                    console.log(data);
                }).error(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });

                $location.path("/home");
            }

            /*controller: 'createNewsFeed',
          templateUrl: 'homepage.html'*/
        }).
```

So redirect the page by itself. Because the authentication works on the backend side, I can get a access token, which is the only thing I really need for future use of my rest api. I defined a route where, after receiving the json with the token, my browser is manually redirected to with $window.location. So when that page is loaded (not visible for the user, it goes too fast to notice) I analyse the token, save the token, analyse authentication, when that is successful I manually redirect to the homepage.